# Como ir para uma segunda activity se o usuário estiver logado facebook sdk

Tags: java, android

Seguinte, um app com uma tela de login com o botão de login do facebook ta implementado certinho.. queria saber como faço para se o usuário já estiver logado ir direto para uma segunda activity, se não estiver voltar para activity de login. obrigado!

Comment: Mostre alguma parte que fez amigo, esta muito vago, é uma dúvida ou uma solicitação ?

Comment: Peguei a implementação nesse site (http://www.learn2crack.com/2015/06/android-facebook-sdk-implementation.html) pois achei a documentação do facebook muito vaga

Comment: Apenas queria verificar se o usuário já esta logado na app